# Is there any way to maintain counts in crontab?

Tags: cron

Need to keep a track of the succeded jobs, on daily basis, with jobs ranging from `/10` `/20` minutes to twice/thrice a day, least for these every 10/20 minutes runs, I'd be interested to know if there are any ways to keep/maintain the counts for thsoe, maybe in the command part after the script's entry, but then how do we neutralize it after /24Hrs, any workable solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

> -add some kind of the timestamp to the job.
>
> -don't redirect anything to the /dev/null .
>
> -set a $MAILTO notification to send output to the required team

We are using Nagios for this and also [cronwatch](https://code.google.com/p/cronwatch/)